# Zend Framework escaping utf8 encoded characters

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am currently pulling in feed data in another languages. I do the following and store into mysql.

```
$content = htmlentities($item->title, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
```

when I output the text, using $this->escape it still escapes the encoded entity.

So I get : `&aacute;` instead of á

Any idea?

Comment: I don't understand what your question is exactly?

Comment: Don't encode data when you store it, encode it when you display it. Also, `Zend_View::escape()` natively uses `htmlspecialchars` with the `UTF-8` encoding unless overridden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do `htmlentities`, do `htmlspecialchars`, `htmlentities` encodes many things that need not or even should not be encoded:

```
$content = htmlspecialchars($item->title, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

If the feed data is not encoded in utf-8, you may need to convert it, *before* `htmlspecialchars`:

```
$content = mb_convert_encoding($item->title, 'UTF-8', '<encoding of the other side>');
```

Note that "encoding of the other side" may prove important.

By the way, if you are going to output it as HTML without any filtering, consider storing it as native HTML.

Comment: thank you! htmlspecialchars fixed the issue without removing $this->escape()!